# Tapestry: Inject at runtime

Tags: java, service, dependencies, code-injection, tapestry

again a small problem by understanding "how tapestry works".

I've got a Tapestry component (in this case a value encoder):

```
public class EditionEncoder implements ValueEncoder<Edition>, ValueEncoderFactory<Edition> {

    @Inject
    private IEditionManager editionDao;

    public EditionEncoder(IEditionManager editionDao) {
        this.editionManager = editionDao;
    }

    @Override
    public String toClient(Edition value) {
        if(value == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return value.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Edition toValue(String clientValue) {
        if(clientValue.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        return editionManager.getEditionByName(clientValue);
    }

    @Override
    public ValueEncoder<Edition> create(Class<Edition> type) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Injecting the the Manager is not working, because the Encoder is created within a page like that:

```
 public void create() {
        editionEncoder = new EditionEncoder();
  }
```

casued by this, i'm forced to use this ugly solution:

```
@Inject
private IEditionManager editionmanager;
editionEncoder = new EditionEncoder(editionManager);
```

Is there a better way to inject components during runtime or is there a better solution in general for it?

Thanks for your help in advance,

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use "new" then tapestry-ioc is not involved in object creation and can't inject. You should inject everything and never use "new" for singleton services. This is true for all ioc containers, not just tapestry-ioc.

Also if you put @Inject on a field then you don't also need a constructor to set it. Do one or the other, never both.

You should do something like this:

```
public class MyAppModule {
    public void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
        binder.bind(EditionEncoder.class);
    }
}
```

Then in your page/component/service

```
@Inject EditionEncoder editionEncoder;
```

If you wanted to put your own instantiated objects in there you can do

```
public class MyServiceModule {
    public void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
        binder.bind(Service1.class, Service1Impl.class);
        binder.bind(Service2.class, Service2Impl.class);
    }
    public SomeService buildSomeService(Service1 service1, Service2 service2, @AutoBuild Service3Impl service3) {
        Date someDate = new Date();
        return new SomeServiceImpl(service1, service2, service3, someDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: yip, that's clear to me. But e.g. in spring it's possible to "force" the injection mechanism with manual instantiated objects. 

I'm looking for a similiar way., i dont' like way with constructor arguments.